# sessionInfo() says windows 10, I'm using windows 11

Tags: r, windows

I'm not sure if this is a problem, but I was looking at my session information and noted that it says it's running under Windows 10. My operating system is Windows 11. Will this cause problems?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11 is still kernel version 10. `sessionInfo` needs to be updated to look at the build number and catch anything >= 22000.